Manhwa in which a female god transfers a guy's soul to other bodies to make him regret attempting suicide
In this manhwa, the main character (a guy) tries to commit suicide to escape reality, but a black/tanned female god is very harsh on him, so he regrets dying. I remember it involved transferring his soul to other bodies to make him regret not appreciating life.
